# Amass vs accumulate - is there a difference or can these be used interchangeably?

Tags: differences

These two words mean pretty much the same thing.
But I couldn't understand the difference.

I picked these two examples from google translate:

> - investigators have yet to accumulate enough evidence
> - starting from nothing he had amassed a huge fortune

Can I swap amass and accumulate in these examples?
Any explanation about differences and distinctions would be nice.

Comment: Offhand I can't think of any (verb) context where they're not interchangeable, but I think I'd probably use ***accumulate*** nearly every time. One potential advantage is if you need a noun, apart from the gerunds ***accumulating, amassing*** there's also ***accumulation***, but I don't think there's any such version of ***amass***

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right but these are TWO words and each one created in a purpose. So we can not ignore one of them and always use another.

Comment: You're very, *very, **very*** wrong if you think these two words were "created for a purpose", and that this somehow implies the "language planners" of centuries ago had any such purpose in mind. Feasibly that might be a meaningful way to look at, say, Esperanto, but it's not how English arose or how it works today. True synonyms are rare because *when* they arise, we either stop using one of the words completely, or we start to use it in contexts that gradually shift the meaning (or retain the original meaning, while the *other* word shifts).

Comment: ...as, for example, ***beef*** today almost always means the *meat* from the animal (butchered, cooked, eaten). Originally it was our "Norman-sourced" word for the animal, and was freely used with that sense. But these days we reserve our "Anglo-Saxon-derived" ***cow*** for the animal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search at Google Books for the best synonym separator:

"Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms"

Once you find it, go to p. 13, to the article on "accumulate" and related words. It tells you:

> ***Amass** refers usually but not always to **things that are valuable**, such as money or treasures [*amass a fortune*]. It frequently implies
>   **more imposing results** than *accumulate*.
>
> Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms: A Dictionary of
>   Discriminated ...*

To me, *amass* implicitly contains an **emphasizer**: it is *accumulate* "to power two":-)

Comment: You're quite right - a worthless/undesirable thing like [***detritus** accumulates*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22detritus+accumulates%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)  an estimated 1150 times in Google Books, but there's not a single instance of [*detritus **amasses***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22detritus+amasses%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). That has to be interpreted in light of the fact that without the word ***detritus*** the "bare" figures are 1179K vs 48k, so in principle there should have been a few dozen hits for my second search there.